# java Maven add dependency

Tags: java, maven

```
java com.companyname.bank.App
```

> Error: Unable to initialize main class com.companyname.bank.App Caused
>   by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/client/ResponseHandler

This report keeps occurring after I added dependency in pom.xml file and related .jar file in /src/lib as well. Really confused and don't know how to solve it.

Plz give me a hand. thx.

Here is my operation process:

1. Copy and paste:

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
     <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
     <version>4.5.6</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

from Maven Repo to my pom.xml

2. Download httpclient.jar to my src/lib
3. mvn clean package
4. cd target/classes
5. java com.companyname.bank.App

Then the error comes.

Comment: Did you add `httpclient-x.x.x.jar` as a dependency in your `pom.xml`? Version might vary based on other dependencies, hence mentioned as `x`.

Comment: What do you mean "and add related .jar in.." ? Did you add the jar manually aside of inserting the dependency? If so, delete the jar you added manually. Maven will take care of it.

Comment: Please provide your pom.xml (only that place where you are adding dependencies). It will be easier to help you. Thank you.

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer                                                                                     
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
       <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
       <version>4.5.6</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: plz check my question again. Thx. @Dumbo

Comment: Try to run your program using the following command `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.companyname.bank.App`

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli): Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory     This new error occurs. Feel sad. @W-S

Comment: You need to execute the command in your project root directory, where your `pom.xml` file is, not in the target/classes directory.

Comment: Yes ! Solved! Could you plz explain the background reason to me?? THx!

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when a compiler could successfully compile the class, but Java runtime could not locate the class file. It usually happens when there is an exception while executing a static block or initializing static fields of the class, so class initialization fails.

[your answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694245/noclassdeffounderror-occurs-even-if-dependency-was-added-to-pom-xml)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the maven exec plugin to launch your app: [doc is here.](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)

"java" itself does not know anything about your maven dependencies.

Try:

> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.companyname.bank.App"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to delete maven repository or `httpclient` folder and then try to build again. you will not get the error again.

Because `httpclient.jar` may corrupt while downloading or it may not downloaded completely due network issues